# How can i start timer immediately in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a little problem. There is something like chess timer. When i press button, current timer stops and second starts, but after 1 second. How can i start second one immediately?
[image: here is form image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        byte sec1;
        byte sec2;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            sec1 = 0;
            sec2 = 0;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender , EventArgs e) {
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Stop();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender , EventArgs e) {
            timer2.Start();
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender , EventArgs e) {
            label1.Text = sec1.ToString();
            sec1++;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender , EventArgs e) {
            label2.Text = sec2.ToString();
            sec2++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are timer1 & timer2 declared? Your image link didn't work for me.

Comment: I think i fixed it

Comment: If you've found a solution, it's worth posting what you found so others might learn from it.

Comment: Nope, i'm still looking for it

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the statement "current timer stops and second starts, but after 1 second". Do you mean that when you click the second button the first timer is stopping and the second one is starting but you want it to fire the tick event immediately rather than waiting for the timer tick time that you have set?

Comment: Why are you using bytes?

Comment: @LarsTech I was just wondering the same thing.

Comment: it's just example. even if i use int there will be same problem

Comment: You're looking for a pause method.  WinForm Timers don't have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**
I know your question is "how to start the timers immediately", but in your code they are starting immediately.  When you call start the timer starts. I believe the effect you are seeing is related to the delay associated with the tick event, which from the description I am assuming is set to a 1 second interval. Since you have said that you are trying to simulate something similar to a chess timer (although in your case counting up as opposed to down), then using something like a stop watch which can start, stop and show elapsed time would be a closer model.  Since there is a Stopwatch class that provides exactly this behavior, I think it would be easier to implement it using two of those and just have a single background thread that updates the UI as frequently as needed. You could even add an update call into each button push to ensure the text boxes are up to date.

===============================

Maybe instead of the timers you should use two instances of the [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.1) class.  This will remove the need for your two variables that you are using to keep track of the seconds as the Stopwatch class will be holding the elapsed time for each counter.

Then in your button methods you could just do this:

```
private Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
private Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

    private void button1_Click(object sender , EventArgs e) {
        sw1.Start();
        sw2.Stop();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender , EventArgs e) {
        sw2.Start();
        sw1.Stop();
    }
```

And then you can use a Background worker or some other background thread that runs and updates your text boxes with the elapsed time from the timers you just need to grab the elapsed time.

```
// This will give you the total number of seconds elapsed.
var timer1Seconds = Math.Floor(sw1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Here is an example of how you can make this update the UI:

```
    private bool _stop = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while(!_stop)
            {
                UpdateElapsedTimes();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateElapsedTimes()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(UpdateElapsedTimes());
            return;
        }

        label1.Text = Math.Floor(sw1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        label2.Text = Math.Floor(sw2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    }
```

Note - in a production program I would not use a boolean as my loop checker, you would use an event handle, and probably a couple of event handles if you wanted to allow pausing the updates, this is just to show an idea of how to do it. You could invoke directly from the thread method and drop the InvokeRequired check, but I added that for additional safety and since it was there I skipped it in the loop.

Comment: `sw1.Elapsed.Seconds` is the wrong property. That only gives you the seconds portion of the duration (values 0-60), you need `sw1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good catch - I was kind of shooting from memory on the properties of TimeSpan. Answer now updated.

Answer (score 0):

The timer *does* start immediately. The problem is that you are not reporting fractions of seconds, so the display will show `0` until a full second has elapsed, which is accurate, technically.

If you want to show `1` immediately, just initialize your variables that way.

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    sec1 = 1;
    sec2 = 1;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to show 1. it's like chess timer. when you press button current timer should stop and second start. But it is wasting 1 second after pressing

Comment: @MateGvenetadze - Like my question above, could you please clarify what is meant by "wasting 1 second"?  Or could you maybe explain what your actual goal is, as maybe the timers with tick events is not the best solution.

Comment: when you press button timer should start immediately. in my code it starts after one second. what you don't understand ?

Comment: @MateGvenetadze - What I don't understand is you saying that it starts one second later. That doesn't make any sense. You are telling the timer to start, it starts immediately, my assumption is that you are not seeing an update until one second later and that is because your tick event is set to fire at 1 second intervals. I just wanted to clarify if that was the case. If you set your tick event to fire at a shorter interval is there a change or is it still waiting 1 second to start.